# Calling ajax function continuously at a specific interval until a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have two jsp pages. One is UI and another is the jsp which gets response.

**UICounter.jsp**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page</title>
<script>
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
      var xmlHttpReq = false;
      // to create XMLHttpRequest object in non-Microsoft browsers
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
          // to create XMLHttpRequest object in later versions
          // of Internet Explorer
          xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (exp1) {
          try {
            // to create XMLHttpRequest object in older versions
            // of Internet Explorer
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (exp2) {
            xmlHttpReq = false;
          }
        }
      }
      return xmlHttpReq;
    }

function makeRequest() {
      var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);
      xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "Control.jsp", true);
      xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
    }

function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {
      // an anonymous function returned
      // it listens to the XMLHttpRequest instance
      return function() {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
              var gotCount = parseInt(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("counterLabel").innerHTML = gotCount;

          } else {
            alert("HTTP errorrr " + xmlHttpRequest.status + ": " + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
          }
        }
      };
    }

</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="counterLabel">0 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">makeRequest();</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Control.jsp**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
if(session.getAttribute("counter") != null && !session.getAttribute("counter").toString().equals(""))
{
    String stringStatus = session.getAttribute("counter").toString().trim();
    int statusCounter = Integer.parseInt(stringStatus);
    session.setAttribute("counter",String.valueOf(++statusCounter));

}else{
    session.setAttribute("counter",String.valueOf(1));
    out.print(session.getAttribute("counter"));
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make ajax calls until a condition (the result is 100) is met. I have tried calling same function (`makeRequest()`) in result of the ajax function while checking till result is 100, but it's not working. Can someone please suggest how to achieve this, example is appreciated? Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: why support old IE xhr? `xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);` probably doesn't do what you think it does, and why return an entire HTML document when you just want the number (presumably) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery and try something like

```
function makeRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Control.jsp",
        success: function (data) {
        if(<your condition>) {
          setTimeout(makeRequest, 100);
        } 
        },
        error: function () {
           // Hanld error
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: I got help from the SO chat and as this is similar, I accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Use **setInterval**

```
function makeRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/xxx/xxx",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //---
        }
    });
}

 /**request all day */
 makeRequest();
 var timer = setInterval(function(){
     console.log("ping..");
     makeRequest();
 },10000);



 /** stop after 3 min or so, if required*/
 setTimeout(function(){
    //stop the timer
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
 },180000);
```

> The **timer** object will come handy to stop the loop later as shown.